# Problems with adding biggest width in style attribute of drop-down menu elements

Tags: jquery, styles, drop-down-menu

I just can't figure out or find any solution here, so I chose to ask a question.
I have plain css/html drop-down menu code, that works and looks fine, but when I add jquery, the problem begins.
As you can see in example below I am trying to add biggest value of same tree (ul.children li) elements Width as the width of all elements within this tree.
Well, the attribute is added, but the value is 0px and remains even if i try to globalize the element range changing *.children* to all *ul*.
What is cousing the code to output 0px instead of needed biggest width value of element.
Thanks in advance!

Here's the plain HTML code:

```
<ul>

   <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="">Sākumlapa</a></li>

   <li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="">Par mums</a>

      <ul class="children">

        <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="">Galerija</a></li>

      </ul>

   </li>

</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
                       $(document).ready(function() {

                            var maxWidth = 0;

                            var elemWidth = 0;


                            $('.children li').each(function() {

                                elemWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));

                                if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > maxWidth) {

                                    maxWidth = elemWidth;

                                }

                             });


                            $('.children li').each(function() {

                                  $(this).css('width', maxWidth + "px");

                            });

                       });
```

And after this is executed you can see that there is style attribute added for the children.li element, but it contains 0px not the biggest width of element.
Here is the Copy&Paste code from browser.

```
<ul>

   <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2">Sākumlapa</a></li>

   <li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=4">Par mums</a>

      <ul class="children">

        <li class="page_item page-item-6" style="width: 0px;"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=6">Galerija</a></li>

      </ul>

   </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line after document is loaded and before the each function:

```
    $('.navigation li').hover(function(){
       // here goes the whole code above
    });
```

This fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

`.outerWidth()` gets the computed width rather than the value set by css. I would recommend you try using it thusly:

```
var maxWidth = 0;
var elemWidth = 0;


$('.children li').each(function() { 
    elemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = elemWidth;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, yes outerWidth works better, but even if I change it, it still returns value of 0px :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                            var maxWidth = 0;

                            var elemWidth = 0;

                            $('.children li').each(function() {

                                elemWidth = parseInt($(this).outerwidth());

                                if (elemWidth  > maxWidth) {

                                    maxWidth = elemWidth;

                                }

                            });

                            $('.children li').each(function() {

                                $(this).css('width', maxWidth + 'px');

                            });

                        });
```

Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/n4CQv/2/

Comment: Because in your example all li's are 100% width. If you set 9 of them to 200px (in your css) and another one 350px. Once page is loaded all of them will be 350px.

Comment: But i dont want to have fixed width, i need that jquery calculates the width of biggest LI (as the innerHTML lenght will always be different).

Comment: All li's will have exactly the same width if you don't specify. If you have all the li's in a container, li's will adapt to your ul's width. That's why in the example all li's go to the end of the screen.

Comment: the last ul's li's ar wrapped becouse of not specified width of li. As i dont need fixed widht, I must set the width of all li elements or parent UL element as the biggest value of the li, so no lis are wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Very close! If this is a dropdown, presumably the dropdowns are set to `display: none` by default in your css, and then shown when the parent is hovered? If that is the case then elements have no dimensions when their display property is none, you need to use `visibility: hidden` to hide them and have them set to `display: block` in your default css, which means they won't be shown but will still occupy their space. Your javsacript is fine, but you can use jquery's `.width()` method to tidy it up a little, plus the second `$.each` method is unnecessary:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var maxWidth = 0;
  var elemWidth = 0;

  $('.children li').each(function() {
    elemWidth = $(this).width();
    if (elemWidth) > maxWidth) {
      maxWidth = elemWidth;
    }
  });

  $('.children li').width( maxWidth );

});
```

Comment: YES! I jsut found it out by testing the whole code (css including). Basically, i have ABSOLUTE positioning for UL UL element and display is set to none. Will try your snipet, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Still 0px and now I cant figure out how to fix this Absolute positioning and diplaying as 'none' issue. I need both: positioning ad n display AND maxWidth values for LI's. :/ Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if I was 100% clear above, you need to set them the .children dropdown to display: block *and* visibility: hidden in your css, and set visibility: visible on hover. Position absolute isn't a problem, nor is maxWidth (unless it is set to 0!)

Comment: If you want to create a http://jsfiddle.net for it, i'd be happy to fix it for you in there.

Comment: Looking at the result in firebug or dev tools, the width is being correctly set on the <li> elements now. If it doesn't look right, you probably need to set the child <a> elements to display block, so they fill the horizontal width. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gzzxw/

Comment: In jsfiddle it shows everything just as i need and everything looks fixed, but when i put these changes in my document, nothing changes. :/ Starting to thing that theres something wrong with my whole project or Wordpress.

Comment: If that's the case, use something like firebug or chrome dev tools to see if there are either any javascript errors or other css that is conflicting.

Comment: Yeah, I am now debugging it. Still, thanks, that was a huge help anyways :)